# Jackson: Get single value without id from JSON array

Tags: java, jackson

I try to access a single value that doesn't have an id in a JsonNode with the help of Jackson.
The JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "annotatedClass": {
            "semanticType": ["T033"],
            "prefLabel": "Oesophageal reflux",
            ...
        }
     }
]
```

I want to get the value of semanticType. I tried it with `String semanticType = currentNode.get("annotatedClass").get("semanticType).at("/").asText()` but this gave me an empty string.

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this:

```
String semanticType = currentNode.get("annotatedClass").get("semanticType").get(0).asText();
```

The key to success was `get(0)`.